# submit button not working in GeckoFX

Tags: c#, button, geckofx, asp.net-webcontrol

I have this code:

```
<input type="button" onmousedown="IamTyping(0);" style="font-size:16px;" value="enter">
```

and tried this in C#:

```
GeckoInputElement enter = new GeckoInputElement(myBrowser.Document.GetElementByTagName("input").DomObject);
enter.click();
```

C# doesn't have any error, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

try the following code

```
GeckoInputElement enter = (GeckoInputElement)myBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    .First(inp => ((GeckoInputElement)inp).Value == "enter");

DomEventArgs ev = browser.Document.CreateEvent("MouseEvent");
ev.DomEvent.InitEvent(new nsAString("mousedown"), true, true);
enter.GetEventTarget().DispatchEvent(ev);

ev = browser.Document.CreateEvent("MouseEvent");
ev.DomEvent.InitEvent(new nsAString("mouseup"), true, true);
enter.GetEventTarget().DispatchEvent(ev);

enter.click();
```

Comment: it doesnt work, Some error have occured. Such as:Error 5 'Skybound.Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement' does not contain a definition for 'GetEventTarget' and no extension method 'GetEventTarget' accepting a first argument of type 'Skybound.Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: What version of Geckofx do you use?

Comment: i used Skybound Gecko 1.9