# How to upload file using Geckofx 60 in VB.NET without opening dialog?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, geckofx

I'm using Geckofx 60 to fill a web form. I have to attach an image file also. I can select/click `Chose file` and Select a file manually. Is there any way to select a local file without opening dialog?

```
    Dim el As GeckoHtmlElement = GeckoWebBrowser1.DomDocument.GetElementsByTagName("input").FirstOrDefault(Function(elz) elz.GetAttribute("type") = "file")
    Dim fileNames = New IntPtr(0) {}
    Dim domInput = Xpcom.QueryInterface(Of nsIDOMHTMLInputElement)(el.DOMHtmlElement)
    domInput.MozSetFileNameArray(fileNames, CUInt(fileNames.Length)) 'Getting Error
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(domInput)
    Dim ev As DomEventArgs = GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.CreateEvent("HTMLEvents")
    Dim webEvent = New [Event](GeckoWebBrowser1.Window.DomWindow, TryCast(ev.DomEvent, nsISupports))
    webEvent.InitEvent("change", True, True)
    el.GetEventTarget().DispatchEvent(ev)
    CustomMarshalers.WStringMarshaler().CleanUpNativeData(fileNames)
```

[image]

I have Got the Error above after checking [How to choose and upload a local file to a website using Geckofx in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158777/how-to-choose-and-upload-a-local-file-to-a-website-using-geckofx-in-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose and upload a local file to a website using Geckofx in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158777/how-to-choose-and-upload-a-local-file-to-a-website-using-geckofx-in-c) It's using `c#`, converting this to `vb.net` shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: I tried this. This does not work on v 60.

Comment: Can you update your post then to include what you've tried? This will help other users know what you've tried so they are not suggesting solutions that you've tried.

Comment: Can you also expand on `This does not work on v 60`, what was the issues if any, was there errors?

Comment: Please check now.